# Realistically what are options does Israel have (after the attacks of 7 october)?

Tags: israel, palestine

On 7 October 2023 Hamas got into Israel from Gaza and killed some 1300 people there. In return, Israel has been bombing Gaza, killing about [10000 people](https://www.npr.org/2023/11/06/1210831466/death-toll-gaza-israel-hamas-conflict) in less than a month.
Israel's allies have publicly come out to defend Israel's 'right to self-defence' (for [example](https://www.euronews.com/my-europe/2023/10/10/israel-has-right-to-self-defence-but-some-actions-counter-international-law-borrell)) even though such bombing cannot defend Israel from terrorist attacks and the vast majority of victims are not terrorists.

Israel has a couple of million people within its borders that it does not want but that really have nowhere else to go. Bombing them does nothing to realistically change the situation.

Is there any merit in the current military actions? It seems to be a case of 'we are hurt, so we want to see the other guys bleed'.
Is there any public discussion of options that would realistically bring the level of violence down, in the short term or maybe longer term?

Comment: Minus the editorializing, asking about proposed alternatives to the current operations might make for a good question.  But it would require those proposals to have originated from either nations, international organizations or high profile politicians/experts (not just our own pundits here).  Not sure if anyone has proposed anything serious, but with the frustration everyone is having with this situation, shutting down a more neutral version of this Q would be premature.